# Cant find Funktion Screenshot() from pyautogui is Not find in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed the package pyautogui with `pip install pyautogui`. All functions of this Package worked fine, But when I type „pyautogui.“ there is no Option to choose the function „Screenshot()“. So only the function Screenshot() is  Not found. I dont know where the issue is but I Hope that I can find the Solution here. Thanks.

Visual Studio Code

Python

Comment: This problem does exist. I submitted [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20244) and can continue to pay attention to it

Comment: So you didnt get a answer?

Comment: You can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3320) on github. This pattern is intentionally not supported. Pyright, the static type checker that underlies pylance, does not model side effects of the import loader.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the language server to **Jedi** by adding the following configuration in ***settings.json***.

```json
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

[image]